# After upgrading to 5.22.0 having trouble with CiviMail HTML editor

Tags: civimail, ckeditor

After upgrading to 5.22.0, the HTML editor field in CiviMail does not show the html menu, and any text saved does not have html commands.
If you look at what is stored in the civi_mail table, there are no html elements.

Any suggestions.

Comment: What setting do you have for wysiwyg editor at civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1

Comment: I have civicrm running under wordpress. How do I find 
civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1